# Using a javascript variable value for <td> tags

Tags: javascript, html

```
function changeFunc9() {
    var selectBox9 = document.getElementById("Schallamach");
    selectedValue9 =selectBox9.options[selectBox9.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(selectedValue9);
 }
var values = [selectedValue1, selectedValue2, selectedValue3, 
selectedValue4, selectedValue5, selectedValue6, selectedValue7, 
selectedValue8, selectedValue9];
```

I didn't include the entirety of my code because it is consistent for the each selectedValue# variable. The selectedValues are coming from select tags in html where a user picks from a list of different options. My function is simply storing their choice in a variable and logging it to the console so I can make sure it worked properly. All I want to do now is use these variables and display the value of the variables in td tags in a table. I am having difficulty with this task. The selectedValues are in an array so that they are global. If anyone could give me some guidance on how to assign these variables to a td, that would be awesome and much appreciated.
I would prefer not to use jQuery. 
Also, I am using a separate js file and linking it to html. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function valuesToTd(values) {
  return values.map((value) => {
    const td = document.createElement("td")
    td.textContent = value
    return td
  })
}

function addToTable(values, table) {
  const tds = valuesToTd(values)
  const tr = document.createElement("tr")
  tds.forEach(tr.appendChild.bind(tr))
  table.appendChild(tr)
}

const selectedValues = ["one", "two", "three"]
const table = document.querySelector("table")
addToTable(selectedValues, table)
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you need to display the data inside the "`values`" array in a row. If that's the case, refer the below code.

HTML - define a table

```
<table border="1"><tr id="dataRow"></tr></table>
```

JS

```
<script>
var values = [selectedValue1, selectedValue2, selectedValue3, 
selectedValue4, selectedValue5, selectedValue6, selectedValue7, 
selectedValue8, selectedValue9];
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("dataRow").innerHTML+="<td>"+values[i]+"</td>"
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, but this is my first project and I'm still learning so there is probably an error elsewhere.